# sequence and series, limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

[Struck with this expression while solving, can you help me solving this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0JgC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us what you've tried and let us know what is confusing you otherwise we can't really help or interact with you. Please read the community rules. A post should look something like this:

## Problem

details...

## Attempt

details...

As far as your actual problem goes...

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n(\frac{\cos(\frac{2n+1)}{n^2+n})\sin(\frac{1}{n^2+n})}{\cos(\frac{2n+3}{(n+1)^2+n+1})\sin(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2+n+1})}-1)$$

Since $n \to \infty$ we really only need to worry about the dominant terms so we can look at

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n(\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{n})\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})}{\cos(\frac{1}{n})\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})}-1)$$

and that should make the answer fairly clear.

Comment: @Rhythmlnk - i got answer of 2 when i solve it

Comment: Not quite. The limit should be 0. Can you tell me why?

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\cos \left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\right)\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)$ actually this the problem @Rhythmlnk

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Please edit your question so people can understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$a_n=\cos \left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\right)\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)$$ Use the classical expansions of cosine and sine and continue with Taylor series to get
$$\cos \left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n}\right)=1-\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ making $$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) }{\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) } \approx \frac{(n-1) (n+1)^3}{n^4}=1+\frac 2n+\cdots$$